# Filter data from pivottable to only current day

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivottable where I amongst others have a date column/row. In a regular table I can put a filter on "current day" however this is not an option in the filters for the pivottable. How can I get only data from the day today, other than copying the data in the pivottable to a regular table and filter there?

Comment: You can filter both column labels and row labels. Can you show an example of your pivot table?

Comment: @CFreitas Yes, I can filter both column and row labels, but I cant find any date conditional filters ("Last week") etc. The pivot table has dates in the first column and some other information in the second.